# Flutter has stopped working on android, how to fix?

Tags: android, flutter

I have a weird problem that started happening. I had my phone connected, and it worked fine when doing the command 'flutter run'. It was USB connected with developer tools active. However, out of nowhere it stopped working.

It stopped recognizing the 'connected devices'

'flutter doctor' don't recognize the device even if the device is properly connected and developers tools active.

Sometimes there is a windows pop up saying that the USB has shown problems and is not recognized.

I already tried flutter doctor, flutter clean, reinstall USB drivers, restart both devices, shut down antivirus and firewalls, update drivers. Change the cables, change the USB port, clean the phone authorizations.

I am in need of using the phone for the debug mode, there is any other way to do it other than USB? Bluetooth or wireless? If not is it possible to fix it?

Comment: Debugging over WiFi is possible. I personally prefer debuggind in an Android emulator, because its very reliable and stable.

Comment: the problem is, when installing adb not even adb reckognizes the phone. It is weird because I can transfer files normally but adb or flutter dont detect the phone and there is the usb error.

Comment: Can you paste the usb error?

Comment: "unknown USB device (Device Descriptor Request Failed)"

Comment: Check if the USB Debugging is checked On, faced this issue a while back when this setting turned itself off when my devices woke up from a reboot.

Comment: It is turned on, I also turned it on and off several times.